# jQuery Mobile Iframe

Tags: jquery-mobile, iframe

How can I show external Website within a iframe in jQuery Mobile.
I have to open an external site in iframe and a back button so that we can go to previous page where iframe is launched. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sample code? this is probably and example for showing iframe in jquery mobile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110833/iframe-in-jquery-mobile-not-showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the popup feature in jquery mobile.It will open the external url in the popup and you can also add controller to close the pop up.

Here is the example http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html